# Why DownloadStringCompleted method always returning same result in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

We are facing one problem with  DownloadStringCompleted method always returning same result in windows phone 7?

First binding the pending requests through service.showing that requuest in listbox placed two buttons.when click on that calling accept service that service update the table.
again while calling the pending request service showing previous result.why please tell me...

Code:

```
private void getpendingrequests()
{
 WebClient wcgetfriends = new WebClient();
                    wcgetfriends.DownloadStringAsync(
                    new Uri("http://{ipaddress}/Network/Reccords/GetFriends?userid=" + userId));
                    wcgetfriends.DownloadStringCompleted +=
                     new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(
                                    wcgetfriends_DownloadStringCompleted);
}



 void wcgetfriends_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender,
                 DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            String resultgetfriends = null, responseCode = null;
            using (var reader = new StringReader(e.Result))
            {
                resultgetfriends = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            XmlReader xmlDoc = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resultgetfriends)));

            while (xmlDoc.Read())
            {
                if (xmlDoc.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {

                    if (xmlDoc.Name.Equals("ResponseCode"))
                    {
                        responseCode = xmlDoc.ReadInnerXml();

                    }

                }

            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(responseCode) == 200)
            {

                string result1 = e.Result.ToString();

                XDocument xmlDocu = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result1)));

                interestrates = (from rts in xmlDocu.Descendants("Friend")

                                 select new SampleCheckedData
                                 {

                                     Id = (string)rts.Element("userid"),
                                     Name = (string)rts.Element("name"),
                                     Icon = (string)rts.Element("imageurl"),

                                 }).ToObservableCollection<SampleCheckedData>();


                this.lstFriendRequuest.ItemsSource = interestrates;

            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(responseCode) == 201)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("UserId is not type of integer");
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(responseCode) == 202)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("User not exists");
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(responseCode) == 203)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Pending Requests");
            }

        }

private void requestaccept()
{
 WebClient wcacceptrequest = new WebClient();
                    wcacceptrequest.DownloadStringAsync(
                    new Uri("http://{ipaddress}/Network/Reccords/FriendRequestAcceptance?userid=" + userId + "&frienduserid=" + _id + "&acceptid=" + 1));
                    wcacceptrequest.DownloadStringCompleted +=
                     new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(
                                    wcacceptrequest_DownloadStringCompleted);
                    Image b = sender as Image;
                    var res = interestrates.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)(e.OriginalSource)).Tag)).ToList();
                    if (res.Count == 1)
                        interestrates.Remove(res.First());
}

   void wcacceptrequest_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender,
                DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            String resultaccept = null, responseCode = null;
            using (var reader = new StringReader(e.Result))
            {
                resultaccept = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            XmlReader xmlDoc = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resultaccept)));

            while (xmlDoc.Read())
            {
                if (xmlDoc.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {

                    if (xmlDoc.Name.Equals("ResponseCode"))
                    {
                        responseCode = xmlDoc.ReadInnerXml();

                    }

                }

            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(responseCode) == 200)
            {

                lstFriendRequuest.ItemsSource = "";
                interestrates = new ObservableCollection<SampleCheckedData>();
                bindGetFriends();

            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(responseCode) == 201)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("UserId is not type of integer");
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(responseCode) == 202)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Friend Id not type of integer");
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(responseCode) == 203)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Accept id not type of integer");
            }

        }
```

please tell me why in bindfriends method getting previous result......

Comment: Why are you creating a `StringReader` just to get a string, when you already *have* the string in `e.Result`? Why are you converting the response code to an integer so many times? Why are you parsing the XML document twice, in different ways? Why are you calling `ToString` on a string? You seem to be going out of your way to make your code convoluted...

Comment: i changed my code as u said but always getting previuos result in downloadstringcomplete metho.

Comment: please help me trying for that not getting...

Comment: May be because you are adding the `DownloadStringCompleted` event handler after the `DownloadStringAsync` statement. Try changing the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly being caused by caching either within the phone or within some network proxy.

There are several things you can try to do in order to prevent caching - if you want to always disable the caching then one of the quickest is to add a unique number to the end of your GET request - e.g.

```
                WebClient wcgetfriends = new WebClient();
                wcgetfriends.DownloadStringCompleted += wcgetfriends_DownloadStringCompleted;
                wcgetfriends.DownloadStringAsync(
                    new Uri(
                        "http://{ipaddress}/Network/Reccords/GetFriends?userid=" 
                        + userId 
                        + "&ignored=" 
                        + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks));
```

---

There are other similar questions and answers at:

- [WP7 HttpWebRequest without caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461610/wp7-httpwebrequest-without-caching)
- [WebClient download weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177698/webclient-download-weird-behavior)
- [Should I disable WebClient caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859137/should-i-disable-webclient-caching)